# Toggle taskbar animations from code

Tags: c++, taskbar

There is a Windows setting whether to enable animations on the taskbar and start menu. If it is enabled (default), new taskbar buttons fade in and on closing a button, the ones after it slowly move one position back. If it is disabled, no animation is displayed and state changes are displayed immediately.

For a console window tool, I want to temporarily disable this animation to avoid unwanted excessive animations. Not sure whether it will help but I'd like to give it a try.

How can I get the current state of this setting and change it to another value? I'm looking for a C++ solution for Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7+.

This is the setting I mean (highlighted):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Don't use a global solution for a local problem

Comment: I don't have a solution but you shouldn't alter a user's global setting for your local problem. You do not 'own' that setting and your application is not the only application that runs on the machine. What if another application is enabeling this setting right after your application disabled it? You create a race condition.

Comment: True, but very unlikely, and technically the only method to control it. I am fully aware that it's a workaround, but there are more workarounds required to change the icon of a console window. Maybe it helps you to see it this way: I want to create a user frontend for this setting.